# Split an ArrayList of objects into chunks of equal size say 1 MB in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory, arraylist, split

I have an `ArrayList<MyObject>`.
 `MyObject` size can vary as it contains an array.

Size of `ArrayList` is 24MB and I want to make it into chunks of 1MB each.

I can't do 24 equal parts and assume each part will be 1 MB as I said that MyObject size is not constant.

Any ideal way to split it into chunks of equal size?

Comment: What jvm your code is supposed to run?

Comment: "Size of ArrayList is 24MB", what are you basing this from?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to you this library: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/, with this you could measure the size of your objects and hence your collections. With a couple of code lines, you could make some validations of size and then create a new collection to insert new elements.

For example here is an standard output:

```
java.util.Hashtable instance footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
         1        64        64   [Ljava.util.Hashtable$Entry;
         1        48        48   java.util.Hashtable
         2                 112   (total) //<--------- Here is your measure
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless java has some hidden API that I'm unaware of it's pretty difficult to get object size in Java--maybe impossible.

Your best bet might be to estimate size based on estimating the size of it's members.

To get a good idea of overhead:

- build a bunch (millions?) of your objects and place them in an array
- run 2 garbage collections in a row
- record current memory usage
- remove the reference to that array so the system can collect it
- run 2 or 3 more gcs
- Record current memory usage
- Subtract your two recordings.

This is probably the most accurate object sizing you'll get, and obviously useless at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** - The pragmatic solution is to change the problem.

First, you say you have an `ArrayList<MyObject>` and yet you are treating them as `Object` for the purposes of finding the size.  (Or at least, that is how people are interpreting your question!)  Finding / estimating the size of an arbitrary `Object` is difficult

**Solution**: add a method to `MyObject` to give an estimate of the size, based on the size of the fixed and variable-sized components.

The more difficult aspect is the packing.  You problem is (I think) a form of the [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).  Getting an optimal packing is an NP-hard problem.

What that means for you is that finding an optimal packing 24MB of objects into 24 equal sized chunks is going to be computationally expensive.  In the worst case, it will be computationally intractable.

Furthermore, there is an edge-case where a solution is impossible; when one of the objects is larger than 1MB

**Solution**: relax the problem by allowing some chunks to go over-size, or by allowing more chunks.  That gives you some simple heuristic solutions.

```
// allow more chunks
chunkNo = 1
for object in objectList:
     if object.size() > chunks[chunkNo].remainingSize()
         chunkNo++
     add object to chunks[chunkNo]

// allow oversized chunks:
sort objectList by object size.
chunkNo = 1;
for object in objectList:
     add object to chunks[chunkNo]
     chunkNo++
     if chunkNo > max
          chunkNo = 1
```

There are other strategies that would give you better packing ... at the cost of more code / computational complexity; e.g. in the first version, try to back-fill small objects into earlier chunks that were under-full.

Comment: I think the main issue of the question is how to measure object size in memory, not how to pack known-sized objects efficiently

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky - I think that pragmatically the OP is better off >>avoiding<< that problem.  And my reading of his Question is that he should be able to do that.

Comment: (Question: "How do I shoot a bullet through my brain that minimizes the damage?"  Answer: "Gently, put the gun down.")